# Show that $\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!n!}$ is an integer where m and n are positive integers and gcd(m,n)=1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I need to prove that $\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!n!}$ is an integer there is a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536644/show-that-fracmnmn-is-an-integer-whenever-m-and-n-are-positive) which is similar to this question but i cant figure out how I can insert the '-1' in there. Thanks

Comment: Statement is not true in general. Take $m=n=2$. In fact, with $m=2$ and $n=2k$, this is false.

Comment: oh, I forgot to write that gcd(m,n)=1

Comment: Special case $\,n\to n+m\,$ in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
$$\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!n!}=\frac{(m+n)}{(m+n)}\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!n!}=\frac{1}{m+n}\binom{m+n}{m}.$$
So we need to show that $\frac{1}{m+n}\binom{m+n}{m}$ is an integer. Observe that $\gcd(m,n)=1$ also implies that $\color{blue}{\gcd(m+n,m)=1}$. Since $\gcd(a,b)$ is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{m+n}\binom{m+n}{m} &=\frac{\color{blue}{\gcd(m+n,m)}}{m+n}\binom{m+n}{m}\\
&=\frac{\color{blue}{x(m+n)+y(m)}}{m+n}\binom{m+n}{m} &\text{for some } x,y \in \Bbb{Z}\\
&=x\left[\color{green}{\frac{m+n}{m+n}\binom{m+n}{m}}\right]+y\left[\color{red}{\frac{m}{m+n}\binom{m+n}{m}}\right].
\end{align*}

The quantity $\color{green}{\frac{m+n}{m+n}\binom{m+n}{m}}=\binom{m+n}{m}$ is definitely an integer and the quantity
$$\color{red}{\frac{m}{m+n}\binom{m+n}{m}}=\binom{m+n-1}{m-1}$$
is also an integer.

This implies  that $\frac{1}{m+n}\binom{m+n}{m}$ is an integer combination of these two integers, hence an integer itself.

Comment: Thank you for answering in such detail, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: This is equivalent to showing that $m+n$ divides $\binom{m+n}{m}$, or equivalently $a$ divides $\binom{a}{b}$ for any $a>b$ where $\gcd(a,b)=1$. See if you can partition the subsets of $a$ objects with $b$ elements into blocks of $a$ to prove this combinatorially. If you know it, you might want to recall the "necklace proof" of Fermat's Little Theorem - this has a similar flavor.